# How can I protect my game account from loss and theft in Clash of Kings?

Tags: clash-of-kings

My friend has lost his [Clash of Kings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hcg.cok.gp) account permanently and I am afraid of losing mine. Do you know the best way to backup my game progress?

Comment: How did he lose it?

Answer (score 1):

**This is important if you play Clash of Kings!**

Since nobody likes losing their accounts, so please watch the video from the Clash of Kings YouTube channel about how to backup, restore and transfer your Clash of Kings. This is a must-see video for all the people who are playing the game. Here is the video: "[Clash of Kings: Save your Game Progress with Google+/Facebook (on Android)](https://youtu.be/YxVGdZ0Ggeg) "

In short, to protect your account, you need to bind it to your Google+/Facebook (on Android) or your Game Center/Facebook (on iOS). If you are playing the game on your computer from the Facebook App Center, then don't worry because your account is already saved to your Facebook!

**NOTE:** *The video is an easy, step-by-step guide from the developer.*